# AWS Kinesis Multipart Upload to an Amazon S3 bucket

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, amazon-kinesis, amazon-kinesis-analytics

I want to do a multipart upload from Kinesis into my Amazon S3 bucket. As Amazon S3 is a file system, for every entry it will create a file under the given bucket name.

My Amazon S3 feeds the AWS glue jobs as it triggers the Lambda function as soon as there is a new file in that particular folder in Amazon S3. With stream data there will be multiple files per second.

How can I control the size of the file on the Kinesis side so that Kinesis only pushes data on an Amazon S3 bucket after the certain threshold is reached? So that I trigger my job whenever I reach that size.

Comment: For Kinesis Data Firehouse you can configure the buffer size and buffer interval.  For S3 as a distination you can set the buffer size up to 128MB before the data is delivered to S3 for example.

Comment: @KevinHorgan     Aah I see, so in that case the Kineses Will hold the data in its own memory just like kafka will hold it in its topic ? and then it full flush it as a single event on a Amazon S3 Bucket?

Answer (score 0):

You can use [AWS Glue Triggers](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/glue/latest/dg/about-triggers.html) instead of lambda.

For example, set a cron time for the Glue.

Comment: This was before putting data into s3 , I think kinesis Firehose will be more suitable. I would love to use Glue jobs later after I have my data into the s3. Also I have to still go over the Glue thing. Will have a more clear picture once I know about it.